# How can I assign scraped data two different variables with same class?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am scraping a website with the following HTML:

[image]

I have the following code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://texastech.com/sports/baseball/stats/2019/oregon/boxscore/14317#play-by-play'
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find(id='inning-all')

innings = results.find_all('table', class_='play-by-play')

for innings in innings:
    situation = innings.find('caption')
    away_team = innings.find('th', class_='text-center')
    home_team = innings.find('th', class_='text-center')
    print(away_team)
    print(home_team)
```

The issue I am running into is that I want to assign the first 'text-center' with the content 'ORE' to the away_team variable while assigning the 'text-center' with the content 'TTU' to the home_team variable.

When I run my code, it assigns 'ORE' to both variables which logically makes sense. I just can't seem to wrap my head around how to select the 'second' 'text-center' and assign it to home_team.

Any suggestions as to how I can accomplish this while neither table heading has a distinguishing class?

Thank you for your time and if there is anything I can add to clarify my question, don't hesitate.

Comment: checkout the `regex.finditer()` method. This way you can loop through all the matches and append them to a list of teams. It however requires to write the regex. This is probably the `beautifulsoup` way: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#going-sideways

Comment: @E.Sommer awesome! I will look at it right now. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You have such problem because `find` function returns only first match which in your case is ORE, use `inning.find_all` to get list and indexes to get first and second match.

Also you have a mistake in your for loop you override innings variable

```
for innings in innings: <-
```